# uiswipegesturerecognizerdirectionup and uinavigationcontroller not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm working with uiswipegesturerecognizerdirectionup and down. It's working properly but when i add UINavigationController swipe not working.
This is my code...

```
//In viewDidLoad

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTapViewController:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(void)didSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
[animation setDuration:1.25];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
CALayer *layer = [self.view layer];
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[self.view.window addSubview:self.view];

}

- (void) onTapViewController: (UIGestureRecognizer *) gesture {
}

- (IBAction)onClickBtn:(id)sender {

GotoNextViewController *gnvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GNVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gnvc animated:NO];

}
```

Here when i click button navigation working properly, but swiping not working.

Comment: what you need to do because your code swipe works with me

Comment: when i add navigation to root view controller it's not working for me

Comment: Are you mean swipe on navigation or its view controller

Comment: I have two view controllers root and second, in root VC i added navigation, swipe and one button. when I click button I want to go second VC.

Comment: Are you using UIScrollView in your main view? if yes, it can't recognize up/down gesture .

Comment: Yes i'm using scrollview in main view controller

Comment: @iOSDeveloper, It's not working because of the default scroll feature which comes with UIScrollView, on swipe it listens to scroll event. If you disable ''Scrolling Enabled" attribute of UIScrollView, it works. It's not a solution to disable scrolling. But you can use left/right swipe instead of up/down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];



and animation

    -(void)didSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
        //    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
        [animation setDuration:1.25];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    }
```

Comment: Navigation working but in root VC swiping not woking

Comment: I'm working with story board, so will check it one more time thank u...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152594/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-abdelahad-darwish).

Answer (score 1):

Add your `GestureRecognizer` into your `navigationController` view like this:

```
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```